# What should I SyncLock in this code, and where?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety, synclock

I have a class that has two method in it, one calls a class which creates and executes a number of threads, the other is an event handler that handles an event raised when those threads complete (and then calls the first method again).

I understand that the method that handles the event runs in the thread that raised the event. So as such, I `SyncLock` a member variable that says how many threads are running and subtract one from it:

```
SyncLock Me ' GetType(me)
    _availableThreads -= 1
End SyncLock
```

So I have a few questions:

**Main Question:** Should I be SyncLock'ing `_availableThreads` everywhere in the class - i.e in the method that creates the threads (which adds 1 when a thread is created)

Side Questions related to this question:

1. I'd usually `SyncLock` the current instance, but I've seen code that `SyncLock`s the type instead, so what is the difference between sync locking `Me` (Current Instance) and `GetType(Me)`?
2. Would there be a performance difference between the two? and is there anything smaller I'd be able to lock for the above that doesn't affect anything else - perhaps a separate 'padlock' object created for the sole purpose of locking things within a class?

Note: The sole purpose of `_availableThreads` is to control how many threads can run at any given time and the threads process jobs that can take hours to run.

Code:

```
Public Class QManager
    Private _maxThreadCount, _availableThreads As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal maxThreadCount As Integer)
        Me.MaximumThreadCount = maxThreadCount
    End Sub

    Public Sub WorkThroughQueue()

        //get jobs from queue (priorities change, so call this every time)
        Dim jobQ As Queue(Of QdJobInfo) = QueueDAO.GetJobList


        //loop job queue while there are jobs and we have threads available
        While jobQ.Count > 0 And _availableThreads <= _maxThreadCount

            //create threads for each queued job
            Dim queuedJob As New QdJob(jobQ.Dequeue)
            AddHandler queuedJob.ThreadComplete, AddressOf QueuedJob_ThreadCompleted

            _availableThreads += 1 //use a thread up (do we need a sync lock here?)***************************
            queuedJob.Process() //go process the job

        End While

        //when we get here, don't do anything else - when a job completes it will call this method again
    End Sub

    Private Sub QueuedJob_ThreadCompleted(ByVal sender As QdJobInfo, ByVal args As EventArgs)

        SyncLock Me //GetType(me)
            _availableThreads -= 1
        End SyncLock

        //regardless of how the job ended, we want to carry on going through the rest of the jobs
        WorkThroughQueue()

    End Sub



#Region "Properties"


    Public Property MaximumThreadCount() As Integer
        Get
            Return _maxThreadCount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            If value > Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 Then
                _maxThreadCount = value
            Else
                value = Environment.ProcessorCount
            End If
            LogFacade.LogInfo(_logger, "Maximum Thread Count set to " & _maxThreadCount)

        End Set
    End Property

#End Region

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to do a few things differently here.

First off, I'd recommend avoiding SyncLock, and using Interlocked.Increment and Interlocked.Decrement to handle changing _availableThreads.  This will provide thread safety for that variable without a lock.

That being said, you still will need a SyncLock around every access to your Queue - if it's being used from multiple threads.  An alternative, if you're using .NET 4, would be to change over to using the new [ConcurrentQueue(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd267265.aspx) class instead of Queue.  If you use SyncLock, you should create a private object only accessible by your class, and use it for all synchronization.

Comment: Very interesting... I wasn't aware of the interlocked class. Thanks.

Comment: Good point about the queue - I'm using 3.5, so unfortunately that isn't possible. Is it possible to rejoin the thread and call the first method? Would you know how to do this? - possibly using thread.join?

Comment: @Mr Shoubs: No, not really.  If you're using 3.5, I'd recommend using a SyncLock on a private object for all access to the Queue - both Enqueue and Dequeue.

Comment: Wouldn't my code keep creating threads from other threads then meaning eventually a memory leak as non of the threads would be garbage collected?

Comment: @Mr Shoubs: As long as you don't block until it's complete, you should be fine.  As soon as the thread's function returns, the thread will go away, and be eligible to be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks... Do you mean it returns when the thread gets to the end of WorkThroughQueue?

Comment: @Mr Shoubs: It looks like queuedJob.Process() starts a new thread.  If that's the case, as soon as that method returns, WorkThroughQueue will return, and the thread will "go away"

Comment: @Reed Copsey, thank you I appreciate your answers, though I'm still not crystal clear - queuedJob is an object that holds data (for the thread to use) and a thread. When the thread completes it raises the threadcomplete event and is handeled by the QueuedJob_ThreadCompleted method which then calls the WorkThroughQueue and so on... so it's looped logic. I understand from what your saying, that when you create a thread it is independent, but as we have threads here that raise an event to create more threads, the thread will only "go away" when it can't create any more threads?

Comment: @Mr Shoubs: After the new thread is created, the logic will continue, and the old one will go away, typically...  Hard to know without seeing the code, though.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't `SyncLock` the instance *or* the type. You always want to `SyncLock` on a variable that is fully within the control of the class, and neither of those are. You should declare a private `New Object` and use that for your `SyncLock`.

```
Private lockObject as New Object()
```

...

```
SyncLock lockObject
   ...
End SyncLock
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the Interlocked class here, the Decrement() method to decrease the count.  Yes, everywhere the variable is accessed.

Using SyncLock Me is as bad as SyncLock GetType(Me).  You should always use a private object to lock on so nobody can accidentally cause a deadlock.  The golden rule is that you cannot lock data, you can only block code from accessing data.  Since the code is your private implementation detail, the object that holds the lock state must also be a private detail.  Neither your object (Me) nor the Type of that object is private.  Allowing other code to lock it by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the thread counter with Semaphore. If you use Semaphore you do not need to exit from while loop and neither it is necessary to call WorkThroughQueue() from ThreadCompleted event handler. Semaphore is thread safe so you can use it without locking.

http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Semaphore

Comment: This is good information, thanks! I'll look into both the method I am using and the semaphore as I want to learn about join the thread as well.